# При попытке отмены голоса "против" во всплывающей плашке текст "часов назад" отображается некорректно ("заэкранированно")

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

[image]

```
&#x447;&#x430;&#x441;&#x43E;&#x432; &#x43D;&#x430;&#x437;&#x430;&#x434;
```

Comment: Связанный репорт: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377743/you-can39t-vote-for-your-own-post