# html теги отображаются как текст в плашке с предупреждением, что вопрос нельзя закрыть как дубликат одним голосом

Tags: дефект

При попытке закрыть вопрос как дубликат, когда сам поставил метку, по которой есть золотой знак, html теги отображаются как текст:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Похожая проблема описана в этом вопросе, но уже устранена: [При попытке отмены голоса "против" во всплывающей плашке текст "часов назад" отображается некорректно ("заэкраниованно")](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11949/1365)